# how to properly shutdown Jackrabbit + MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, jackrabbit

we have an application written in Java (Spring Boot) that uses Jackrabbit with MongoDB, this is MongoDB config:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class MongoRepositoryInitializer {
    @Value("${oak.mongo.db}")
    private String mongoDbName;

    @Value("${oak.mongo.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    @Bean
    public Repository repository(DocumentNodeStore documentNodeStore) {
        return new Jcr(new Oak(documentNodeStore)).createRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                .maxConnectionIdleTime(30000)
                .build();
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + mongoUri));
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDatabase mongoDatabase(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDbName);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoBlobStore mongoBlobStore(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        return new MongoBlobStore(mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDbName));
    }

    @Bean
    public DocumentNodeStore documentNodeStore(MongoClient mongoClient, MongoBlobStore mongoBlobStore) {
        return MongoDocumentNodeStoreBuilder
                .newMongoDocumentNodeStoreBuilder().setMongoDB(mongoClient, mongoDbName, 16)
                .setBlobStore(mongoBlobStore)
                .build();
    }
}
```

we have two frustrating problem with MongoDB (or maybe jackrabbit). the first problem is that after a while that we have started the app we get the following error:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.DocumentNodeStore
 - Background operation failed: org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plug
 ins.document.DocumentStoreException: This oak instance failed to update
 the
 lease in time and can therefore no longer access this DocumentNodeStore.
 org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.DocumentStoreException: This
 oak
 instance failed to update the lease in time and can therefore no longer
 access this DocumentNodeStore.
```

we can only get ride of this error by restarting MongoDB.

the second problem is that after restarting the app (without MongoDB restart) we get the following logs, and we have to wait for a while (approximately 100 seconds) for app complete start up:

```
2020-05-03 16:12:44.059  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.0.176:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2020-05-03 16:12:44.176  INFO 13854 --- [168.0.176:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:36}] to 192.168.0.176:27017
2020-05-03 16:12:44.182  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2020-05-03 16:12:44.183  INFO 13854 --- [168.0.176:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=192.168.0.176:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 5]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=5367075}
2020-05-03 16:12:44.205  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:37}] to 192.168.0.176:27017
2020-05-03 16:12:44.462  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.d.mongo.MongoDocumentStore     : Connected to MongoDB 4.2.5 with maxReplicationLagMillis 21600000, maxDeltaForModTimeIdxSecs 60, disableIndexHint false, clientSessionSupported false, clientSessionInUse true, serverStatus WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, fsync=null, journal=null
2020-05-03 16:12:44.489  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.document.ClusterNodeInfo       : Found an existing possibly active cluster node info (12) for this instance: mac:525400bb0ae9//home/mehrdad/epic/parent, will try use it.
2020-05-03 16:12:44.489  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.document.ClusterNodeInfo       : Waiting for cluster node 12's lease to expire: 106s left
2020-05-03 16:12:49.492  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.document.ClusterNodeInfo       : Waiting for cluster node 12's lease to expire: 101s left
2020-05-03 16:12:54.495  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.document.ClusterNodeInfo       : Waiting for cluster node 12's lease to expire: 96s left
2020-05-03 16:12:59.498  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.document.ClusterNodeInfo       : Waiting for cluster node 12's lease to expire: 91s left
2020-05-03 16:13:04.500  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.document.ClusterNodeInfo       : Waiting for cluster node 12's lease to expire: 86s left
2020-05-03 16:13:09.502  INFO 13854 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.j.o.p.document.ClusterNodeInfo       : Waiting for cluster node 12's lease to expire: 81s left
```

it seems these problem are related.

I have searched the internet, some people says this is because of a bad shutdown of the jackrabbit server, but I could not find the proper way to shutdown server.  I will appreciate any recommendations

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you should check the system log; maybe the Mongo instance was unresponsive for more than 120s?

For the second problem: you need to make sure that upon shutdown the DocumentStore's dispose method is called.

Comment: MongoDB is not unresponsive, a always can login by `mongo` command

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue in our application, we were getting this Exception when there were some network issue in connection between database and application server or database was down. So we implemented LeaseFailureHandler in application which is handling this exception and retrying to established connection with database whenever connection issue resolved. By this we do not need to manually restart application, Document node store will automatically restart whenever connection established.

```
                documentNodeStore.setLeaseFailureHandler(new LeaseFailureHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleLeaseFailure() {
                        log.info("Execute LeaseFailureHandler to avoid manual restart of Application.");
                        try {
                            restartDocumentNodeStore(dbDetails, 0);
                        } catch (final RepositoryException re) {
                            log.warn("Error in LeaseFailure Handler: ", re);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
```